# Apply different CSS stylesheet depending on browser window size - I can't find anything definitive

Tags: html, css

help me please if you'd be so kind...

I am having some difficulty pinpointing how best to go about this, as Google's new algorithm isn't being very helpful with my (spot on) search terms.

[My site](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) is 100% fluid width and I need to change stylesheets for users at 1152 / 1024 and below.  I started off with the following piece of jscript to detect the resolution and apply these new stylesheets, but it doesn't work in IE - just great.

I understand that a stylesheet based on the actual browser window is best, but the content has a max-width of 1280px, so huge resolutions with minimised window's won't be affected I hope, and I doubt users will bother to minimise their windows if they're on resolutions on 1024 and below.

Here's my current code placed in the head:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var screenwidth = screen.width;
if (screen.width < 1280){
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/Templates/Common/Public/1024res.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
</script>
```

So, my questions are: 1) Why doesn't this work in IE? And 2) Is this the best route, especially considering jscript may be disabled?  Does anyone know how best to achieve this?

Any help - much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The Non-javascript method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1152px)" href="800.css" />
```

See: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I tried this and it doesn't work in IE either!  Any ideas why??  Thanks :)

Comment: IE 8.. Just can't get any of it to work!  Any other suggestions? I am desperate to make this work... users are bouncing as I type and I've tried a few, but so far nothing works cross-browser

Comment: If you have it working in IE7, you can cheat by forcing 8 into 7 mode by putting this as the FIRST meta tag in <head> -- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />

Comment: Notice that it is *device* width, not browser width. Regardless of browser window size, your device will report whatever is the resolution of your screen.