# How to LOAD different css files based on screen size - still missing good answer

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

First of all I know that this question was asked a lot before, but every answer was false or outdated.

Here is my problem: I want to **load** different CSS files based on device width. Here is the answer that is always given and that is false:

```
<link media="screen and (min-width: 721px)" rel="stylesheet" href="./cs/styles.css" />
<link media="screen and (max-width: 720px)" rel="stylesheet" href="./cs/styles-min.css" />
```

The problem with this answer is that the **both files are loaded** --->> **both files are sent to us on HTTP request**. Here is the proof on mozilla:

[image]

My question is how do I get **only one** to be loaded/sent to us on HTTP request. Btw I don't want to use js or server-side language if not necessary, if I really really have to, thats ok but give me reasons why your way is better. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using media queries in your css file. Only one css file is needed, and you specify when the screen size is smaller, then the style wrapped inside media queries will override

Comment: Bc I want ultra-fast performance, I have a lot of JS(about 100kb) and CSS(about 20kb) and I don't want to add unnecessary "weight"  to page cuz there is A LOT of css to be changed for it to be adapted to mobile. Am I right or maybe my tought proccess is bad?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254517/how-do-i-include-css-based-on-screen-size-of-the-device

Comment: Yes I did, same answers and one has really bad practice and that is using @import

Comment: Maybe you didn't get me. I am trying to load one file if user is mobile user(small screen) and the other one is the user is desktop user(big screen) and not include them both on the same page (so they would't cause it to be "heavy")

Answer (score 0):

IE 9+, Firefox 3.6+, Safari 3+, Any Chrome, Opera 10+. Mozilla suggests starting the media attribute of the  with “only” which will hide the stylesheet from older browsers that don’t support media queries. That may or may not be what you actually want to do… case dependent of course.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='css/wide.css' />link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css"/>
```

Are seen this ref : https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Demo : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResolutionDependantLayout/example-one.php

Comment: This is not what I want, on the link "Demo" link that you sent, we can see **all files** sent through HTTP request but thanks for the answer!