# How to change content ( substitute text, images etc.) on different resolutions ( with or without bootstrap)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

Say, I want to change text or pictures for different device resolutions , not size of text but completely different text or even div, is there is a way to do this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336539/apply-different-css-stylesheet-depending-on-browser-window-size-i-cant-find-a UPD: and the column "Related" on the right

Comment: Well, its a good way, but not suitable for big changes, like divs with multiple elements inside. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [available classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes):

[image: table of classes]

For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">This device is <span class="visible-xs-inline">extra small</span><span class="visible-sm-inline">small</span><span class="visible-md-inline">medium</span><span class="visible-lg-inline">large</span></h1>
  <img class="visible-xs-block center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIuT0.png" alt="phone">
  <img class="visible-sm-block center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA6ZP.png" alt="tablet">
  <img class="visible-md-block center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IekS.png" alt="notebook">
  <img class="visible-lg-block center-block" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oaMK.png" alt="desktop">
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, it works just like I need it to. I thought these classes can be used just along with col-*-* ones, not in any tag. Thanks a lot.